# Can a person be non-DDoSable?

Tags: ddos

I have a friend who claims he cannot be DDoSed by a conventional web booter.

We have tested this with him multiple times.

The public IP given to us when he joins a server, I.e. client connection info on teamspeak3, is the ip that we try to stress via dns.

We use conventional methods to test this- but we are now curious, why is this the case? His public IP seems to remain the same when the attack hits.

**Could someone explain why he experiences no lag from this? Why is his internet specifically like this, unlike others?**

Comment: Your friend is BS'ing you, you know it, and just because *you* haven't been able to doesn't mean it's generally impossible.

Comment: I don't recommend "testing" this, it's a pretty bad idea. Also, your conventional methods are probably nowhere near the scale of what a real attack would be

Comment: You stress the IP "via dns"? I think you are using the wrong attack .....

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From a theoretical perspective this is impossible. The base of a distributed denial of service attack is flooding a system with so many requests it cannot keep up. No matter how little resources a system uses for processing, you can always add more requests to increase utilization, eventually reaching capacity.

From a practical perspective, yes, this can be the case. You have very little available attack power. There are many companies that have sufficient processing power to handle your attacks; your friend could be using one of them as an upstream, and malicious requests get dropped before ever reaching his local system. This is the basic idea behind anti-DDoS services.

Answer (score 1):

Like Xiong said:

> From a theoretical perspective this is impossible. The base of a denial of service attack is flooding a system with so many requests it cannot keep up.

Expanding on this there are multiple types of DDoS attacks, each exploiting a different type of resource.  So lets take a moment and understand DDoS attacks better.

---

### Application-layer floods

Every device on the internet has a max processing power, max memory storage, and max number of connections.  Your desktop could be a $4000 gaming rig capable of playing latest and greatest games at peek performance.  However, upstream of that gaming rig is a router ... most home routers have 100 Hhz - 1 Ghz procs (occasionally more than one) and between 20 Mb to 1 Gb of ram.  In order for a router to work, it has an application running on it that handles the communication of your network ... these applications can often be abused in such a way that it will cause your device to lock up due to exhaustion of processing power or memory.

**Sophisticated low-bandwidth Distributed Denial-of-Service Attack**

If you have SSH, Telnet, HTTP, or HTTPs externally exposed for configuration an attacker could attempt to login thousands of times a second ... each request would cause the processor to hash the password provided and then compare it to its configuration.  Hashing is computationally expensive by design and the processor will eventually get to a point where computing the hashes will effect network traffic.

Another example is the application on your desktop itself ... TS3 has the same limitations of processor power and memory. They are most likely far greater than that of your router, however, if someone knew the TS3 server information and could spoof its session information and ip ... it could send you thousands of "User Joined" / "User Left" messages a second ... and your computer would eventually crash.  This is true of not just TS3 but any application that you use that connects to the internet.  In many cases the application being attacked is a webserver or something dealing with authentication (due to hashing being computationally expensive).  Very simple applications can cause lots of trouble ... if you would like to see this in action checkout [Fork Bombs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fork_bomb) which are very very short pieces of code that will easily bring any computer to its knees.  They will not permanently harm your computer ... but you will most likely need to reboot after running one.

**Teardrop attacks**

Networking allows for large packets to be broken into smaller packets ... its just one of the many things IPv4 does to get things to work.  Routers are sometimes tasked with the job of putting the pieces of that packet back together before handing it off to your desktop.  If an attacker tells a router that it has such a packet and keeps giving more and more bogus pieces of this never-ending packet ... the router can sometimes be fooled into filling up its entire memory ... causing network traffic to hang.

**(S)SYN flood**

This occurs when an attack sends a flood of TCP/SYN packets to a computer.  The computer then has to reply with a TCP/SYN-ACK telling the attacker that the first packet was received and an TCP/ACK packet is requested from the attacker at a specific ethereal port.  The problem is the attacker has no intention of sending the final TCP/ACK packet and the connection remains open on your computer until it times out.  The problem here is that your computer only has 65,535 TCP ports and each port by default times out after 12s ... meaning that if you can generate 5462 packets a second (easily doable from one computer) you can prevent a device from making any new connections to the internet.

---

### Distributed DoS

Every device on the internet has a max bandwidth it can obtain. This max bandwidth is either due to the limitation of the devices own hardware (ex a rPI can not handle GigE), the hardware upstream of the device (ex your wifi a/b router), or limitations put on you by your ISP ... every single device on the internet is bottle necked by one of these three things.

If your connection to the internet is 200 Megabit Up 200 Megabit Down and someone hits you with 1 Tbps [ref](https://thehackernews.com/2016/09/ddos-attack-iot.html) or 1.5 Tbps [ref](https://arstechnica.com/security/2016/09/botnet-of-145k-cameras-reportedly-deliver-internets-biggest-ddos-ever/) ... your internet connection simply will not be able to handle the load ... there is pretty much nothing you can do beyond switching to a different IP and even if you do if the attack is instead targeted at one of your ISP's router it too can be taken out (thus preventing you from simply switching to a new IP).

The the internet is essentially ["A series of tubes"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Series_of_tubes) ... and they can be too full to handle any more traffic.

---

> is it possible to be 100% safe from DDoS

... No, given enough resources google.com could fall pray to a DDoS.  It is possible to safeguard yourself from many of the Application-layer flood attacks, however, everything has limits.

Comment: Are you saying application layer attacks target your router? And that e.g. SYN flood is a type of application layer attack? Because that's simply wrong.

Comment: Im saying application layer attacks CAN target your router ... they can target other things as well.  As far as the SYN flood, lets less important how you classify it and more important to understand how it works.

Answer (score 0):

Sticking to the main question: The answer is **mostly**. A lot of services do contain potential vulnerabilities that can be exploited to create a DoS condition. Especially older services on older OS's. Theoretically, you can uninstall all externally-facing services / implement heavy IP filtering to prohibit potential intent of external hackers DoSing the service. A disturbingly-common thought is people thinking that they need to be individually targeted for their service containing a DoS or otherwise to be exploited. In reality, there are botnets hitting any IP address that is internet-facing and scanning them for whatever vulnerabilities they want to exploit.

Now with that said, is making yourself 100% DoS safe practical? **No.** Any Joe Schmoe on the street can have an 0-day to your service or network that no one else knows about. Fun times.